# How to only display the $exception->message on the 404 error page when debug=true in .env

Tags: laravel, debugging, http-status-code-404

My 404.blade.php file is this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <h3 class="page-title">@lang('global.app_oh_no')!</h3>

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row" >
                <h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;@lang('global.app_sorry_were_not_able_to_find_the_page_you_are_looking_for').</h4>

                <h4> &nbsp;&nbsp;{{$exception->getMessage()}} </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

@stop
```

I've been asked to modify it so that the code line`{{$exception->getMessage()}}` only displays for errors when, "debug=true in .env"

The problem is I don't know what that means or how to approach it.

My env. file is set as  `APP_DEBUG=true` and my app.php file is set as `'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),`

So how might I go about modifying this so that the $exception->getMessage() only displays to view for 404 errors issues when debug=true in .env

Does this make sense to people, I am at a loss for what the expected action would be. I guess I am failing to understand the concept as well as the plan of action.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a condition

```
@if (config('app.debug'))
    {{ $exception->getMessage() }}
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution,  I will give it a try. Might you also be able to help me understand what is transpiring here? I guess I don't understand what and how things are being accessed during the debug process and how the new solutions modifies the original action.